# Adding a line on an svg with image in background in d3

Tags: d3.js

Hi Everyone,
            I need some suggestions on a task i have been trying to do while learning d3. I have an svg with an image in the background. I am trying to draw a path on this svg post attaching the image. 
While drawing a line on svg is not giving me trouble but once i add image and then try to draw perhaps the lines drawn go behind the image and aren't visible. 
below is what i am trying:

```
var lineData = [{"Y": 778, "X": 256}, {"Y": 736, "X": 635}];

var linePathGenerator = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.X; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.Y; })
    .interpolate("linear");

//check to see if SVG Path Mini-Language Instructions are generated
linePathGenerator(lineData);

var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", "800")
    .attr("height", "800").append("image")
     .attr("xlink:href", "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/qn8dzj5057urskc/blank.jpg");


var svgPath = svgContainer
  .append("path")
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("stroke-width", "4px")
    .attr("fill", "none");

svgPath.attr("d", linePathGenerator(lineData));
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the line was not displayed is, it was rendering inside the image tag.

```
var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", "800")
    .attr("height", "800").append("image")
     .attr("xlink:href", "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/qn8dzj5057urskc/blank.jpg");
```

Here, the svgContainer's reference is to the image tag rather than the svg.

To fix this use

```
var lineData = [{"Y": 10, "X": 10}, {"Y": 100, "X": 100}];

var linePathGenerator = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.X; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.Y; })
    .interpolate("linear");

//check to see if SVG Path Mini-Language Instructions are generated
linePathGenerator(lineData);

var svgContainer = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", "800")
    .attr("height", "800");

svgContainer.append("image")
     .attr("xlink:href", "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/qn8dzj5057urskc/blank.jpg");


var svgPath = svgContainer
  .append("path")
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("stroke-width", "4px")
    .attr("fill", "none");

svgPath.attr("d", linePathGenerator(lineData));
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/GunnerSS/7fvtcLrw/